# How can we get the events of calling on Agora Video Call on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, agora.io

How can I get the following events?

1. Initiate Call event
2. Call received event
3. Call missed event
4. Call end event

Answer (score 0):

You can use onConnectionStateChanged() callback for most of these functions.
You can read about these functions over here:
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_channel_event_handler.html#a6dfbfe241ac004b792a499c29033ddff